# volley status code 200 is considered as error response in 5.0.2

Tags: android, android-volley

i have been using volley in my app. i have tested my app in version 5.0.2 device it throws exception like..

```
05-15 14:56:02.374: E/Volley(23574): [18922] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 200 for http://sample_url.com (sample url)
05-15 14:56:02.380: E/AndroidRuntime(23574): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-18922
05-15 14:56:02.380: E/AndroidRuntime(23574): Process: com.example.jadoofy_android, PID: 23574
05-15 14:56:02.380: E/AndroidRuntime(23574): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.android.volley.NetworkResponse.statusCode' on a null object reference
05-15 14:56:02.380: E/AndroidRuntime(23574):    at com.android.jadhoofy.backend_tracker_volley.BackEndHelper_volley$3.parseNetworkError(BackEndHelper_volley.java:480)
05-15 14:56:02.380: E/AndroidRuntime(23574):    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.parseAndDeliverNetworkError(NetworkDispatcher.java:149)
05-15 14:56:02.380: E/AndroidRuntime(23574):    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:138)
```

response code 200 is considered as a error response. but it works fine in all other versions

Comment: did you get the answer ?

Comment: what http stack are you using ?